# Implementing jquery read more & show less for dynamic li tags

Tags: jquery, html

In my code ***li*** tag is generated using php. It is dynamic , some times there may be more than 3 ***li*** tags , some times less than 3 ***li*** tags . In this case i have to show 'read more' and 'show less' when ***li*** tags are more than 3 .

Here i am showing my html and jquery what i tried. Is there any other easy method to implement this .

```
        <html>
     <head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){

         var a = $(".bul5 li").length;

         if (a > 3)
         {
             $("ul li:nth-child(3)").append("<span class='readMore'> Read More...</span>");

         }
         for( i = 3; i<a; i++ )
         {
            $("li").eq(i).hide();

         }
         $('.readMore').click(function(event){      
            for( i = 3; i<a; i++ )
            {

               $("li").eq(i).show();
               $(this).hide();


            }

            $("ul li:nth-child("+i+")").append("<span class='showless'> Show Less...</span>");


            $('.showless').click(function(event){      
             for( i = 3; i<a; i++ )
             {
                $(this).hide();
                $("li").eq(i).hide();
                $('.readMore').show();


             }
            });


         });
       });




    </script>
     </head>
    </html>

    <body>
     <!-- below part is generted from my php code -->
     <ul class="bul5" style="font-size:13px;">
        <li>Samsung Galaxy Note 3 comes with <b>Android  v4.3 Jelly Bean OS</b>.</li>
        <li>It has a <b>1.9 GHz Octa Core Processor</b> and <b>3 GB RAM</b>.</li>
        <li>Samsung Galaxy Note 3 has <b>5.7 Inches Screen</b> with <b>Full HD Display</b>.</li>
        <li>It has a <b>13 MP Rear Camera</b> and <b>2 MP Front Camera</b>.</li>
        <li>Samsung Galaxy Note 3 has <b>3G</b> Connectivity.</li><li>It has <b>FM Radio</b>.</li>
        <li>The Phone is powered by <b>Li-ion 3200 mAh </b> standard battery with <b>Upto 21 hours</b> Talktime.</li>
     </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b9Qgj/1/

Comment: Please let me know if given demo not working as per your expected

Comment: @YogeshSharma My code is working fine as per my expectation , But what i am asking is there any other short method in jquery other than i coded.

Comment: so my given code is not working as per your requirements

Comment: @YogeshSharma in the third li tag i should get 'read more...' at the end of the point and in the last li end i should get 'show less'

Comment: @YogeshSharma . Look at your demo here. http://jsfiddle.net/XqZsE/9/ . Read more & Read less has to come along with the paragraph inside li. It should not come in the next line

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/XqZsE/10/ fiddle

Comment: I think it's a HTML change you can do it on your end by applying simple css as you can see I have applied display:block simply remove this and it will work as inside a paragraph

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56764/discussion-between-yogesh-sharma-and-raaga).

Answer (score 1):

You can use below given JS for reference

```
  $('.media-item').hide();
    $('.media-item').slice(0, 3).show();
    $('.view-less-text').hide();
    var length=$('.media-item').length;
    $("ul li:nth-child(3)").append("<span class='media view-all-text'> Read More...</span>");
    $('ul li:nth-child('+length+')').append("<span class='media view-less-text'> Read Less...</span>");
    $('.media').click(function () {
        var $relatedItems = $('.media-item').slice(3);
        if ($('.media-item').hasClass('show')) {
            $relatedItems.hide().removeClass('show');
            $('.view-all-text').show();
            $('.view-less-text').hide();
        }
        else {
            $relatedItems.slideDown('slow').addClass('show');
            $('.view-all-text').hide();
            $('.view-less-text').show();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Check Now [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XqZsE/10/)

Comment: Please check demo I have created

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

There is a very small issue. 
Just replace this:

```
$('this').hide();
```

with this:-

```
$(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ var a = $(".bul5 li").length;

     if (a > 3)
     {
         $(".bul5 li:nth-child(3)").append("<span class='readMore'> Read More...</span>");

     }
     for( i = 3; i<a; i++ )
     {
        $(".bul5 li").eq(i).hide();

     }
     $('.bul5 .readMore').click(function(event){   

        $('.bul5 .readMore').hide();

        for( i = 3; i<a; i++ )
        {

           $(".bul5 li").eq(i).show();
           $('this').hide();


        }

        $(".bul5 li:nth-child("+i+")").append("<span class='showless'> Show Less...</span>");


        $('.bul5 .showless').click(function(event){   

          $('.bul5 .showless').hide();

         for( i = 3; i<a; i++ )
         {
           $(this).hide();
            $(".bul5 li").eq(i).hide();
            $('.bul5 .readMore').show();


         }
        });


     });
   });
```

This is the js with proper read more and showless